# How do you unlock the Tog_ImLame achievement?

Tags: tower-of-guns

How do you, then, unlock this achievement?

<sup>I am reluctant to make this post, but the cat is out of the bag now.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

The short version is:

1. Enable the console (Options → Enable Console)
2. Start a game
3. Hit Tab
4. Type in `Tog_ImLame SUPER0451LOL`
5. Hit Enter.
6. Pat yourself on the back for your leet googling skills.

*"Ah, badp. But whenceforth dost that gibberish come? Surely there must have been a way to find out!"*

That's the long version of the answer, and since that is not a story that is mine to publish, I'm holding my tongue. :)

Comment: *"since that is not a story that is mine to publish..."* - So how about providing a source?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft How about you try it for yourself and see that it works? :)

Comment: I don't have the game, but not mentioning how the code is obtained makes this answer incomplete.